# Does "grasp the road condition" sound strange?

Tags: verbs

The following sentence is created when my language is translated into English using my dictionaries:

> To drive safety, it is necessary to **grasp** the road condition.

After googled, I found that this usage is less common.  It seems that "know" is common. Is using "grasp" sound strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grasp** is synonymous with **know**/**comprehend**/**understand**, although it is important to note that grasp also has other definitions that have nothing to do with those words.

> English grammar is difficult to **grasp**.
>
> The wrestlers **grasped** at one another.

Using **grasp** there wouldn't confuse any native speaker and is technically correct. However, the most common version of that phrase doesn't use any synonyms of **know**:

> To drive safely, it is necessary to **check** the road condition.

That is, you should always either check the radio, the television, the internet, etc. about weather and other things that could cause unsafe road conditions.

Side note: beginning a sentence (or independent clause) with the pronoun "it" without a noun before it is poor form in written English. It is so common in spoken English that it is deemed a lost cause, though.

> The box is on the table. **It** is brown. (Correct)
>
> **It** wasn't until she laid down that she realized how tired she was. (Incorrect)

Answer (score 2):

**Grasp** is the wrong word here.

Note that one should drive **safely** (adverb) and not **safety** (noun).

The sentence would read better as:

> To drive safely, one should take the road conditions into account

or

> To drive safely, one should **consider/allow for/factor in** the condition of the road.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/allow%20(for)